# Is it possible to optimize this nested loop?

Tags: c, optimization, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I am working on a project in which i want to convert a given video input stream into block sections (so it can be used by a hardware codec). This is project is run on an STM32 microcontroller running a 200Mhz clock.

The received input is a YCbCr 4:2:2 progressive stream, which basically means the input stream looks like this for every row:

```
Size:      32 bit word    32 bit word    32 bit word    ...
Component: Cr Y1 Cb Y0    Cr Y1 Cb Y0    Cr Y1 Cb Y0    ...
Bits:      8  8  8  8     8  8  8  8     8  8  8  8     ...
```

This stream needs to be converted into a block format used by a hardware codec. The codec accepts a byte array in a specific order. Currently i am doing this using a nested loop for every 1/8 of an image frame using lookup tables and writing into an empty array:

Defines:

```
#define ROWS_PER_MCU                    8
#define WORDS_PER_MCU                   8
#define HORIZONTAL_MCU_PER_INPUTBUFFER  40
#define VERTICAL_MCU_PER_INPUTBUFFER    8
```

Global variables are declared like this:

```
typedef struct jpegInputbufferLUT
{
    uint8_t JPEG_Y_MCU_LUT[256];
    uint8_t JPEG_Cb_MCU_422_LUT[256];
    uint8_t JPEG_Cr_MCU_422_LUT[256];
}jpegIndexLUT;

jpegIndexLUT jpegInputLUT;

uint8_t jpegInBuffer[81920];
uint32_t rawBuffer[20480];
```

Look up tables are created like this:

```
void JPEG_Init_MCU_LUT(void)
{
    uint32_t offset;

    /*Y LUT */
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            offset =  j + (i*8);
            if((j>=8) && (i>=8)) offset+= 120;
            else  if((j>=8) && (i<8)) offset+= 56;
            else  if((j<8) && (i>=8)) offset+= 64;

            jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Y_MCU_LUT[i*16 + j] = offset;
        }
    }

    /*Cb Cr LUT*/
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            offset = i*16 + j;

            jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Cb_MCU_422_LUT[offset] = (j/2) + (i*8) + 128;

            jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Cr_MCU_422_LUT[offset] = (j/2) + (i*8) + 192;
        }
    }
}
```

Conversion code:

```
/* Initialize variables for array conversion */
uint32_t currentMCU = 0;
uint32_t lutOffset = 0;
uint32_t inputOffset = 0;
uint32_t verticalOffset = 0;

/* Convert X rows into MCU blocks for JPEG encoding */
for(uint8_t k = 0; k < VERTICAL_MCU_PER_INPUTBUFFER; k++)
{
    for(uint8_t n = 0; n < HORIZONTAL_MCU_PER_INPUTBUFFER; n++)
    {
        inputOffset = verticalOffset + (n * 8);
        lutOffset = 0;

        for(uint8_t i = 0; i < ROWS_PER_MCU; i++)
        {
            for(uint8_t j = 0; j < WORDS_PER_MCU; j++)
            {
                /* Mask 32 bit according to DCMI input format */
                uint32_t rawBufferAddress = inputOffset+j; // Calculate rawBuffer address here so it only has to be calculated once
                jpegInBuffer[jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Y_MCU_LUT[lutOffset] + currentMCU]       = (rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] & 0x7F);
                jpegInBuffer[jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Cb_MCU_422_LUT[lutOffset] + currentMCU]  = ((rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] >> 7) & 0x7F);
                jpegInBuffer[jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Cr_MCU_422_LUT[lutOffset] + currentMCU]  = ((rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] >> 23) & 0x7F);
                jpegInBuffer[jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Y_MCU_LUT[lutOffset+1] + currentMCU]     = ((rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] >> 16) & 0x7F);

                lutOffset+=2;
            }
            inputOffset += 320;
        }
        currentMCU += 256;
    }
    verticalOffset += 2240;
}
```

This conversion is currently taking me about 8 ms, and this needs to be done 8 times. This is currently taking up almost all of my available execution time, since i am trying to get 15 fps out of my system.

Is it in any way possible to speed this up? I was thinking maybe sorting the input array instead of just writing into a new buffer, but would swapping 2 elements in an array have a faster execution time than copying values into another array?

Would love to hear your ideas/thoughts on this,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an idea, try it, measure it - no one can definitively tell you whether it will be faster.  So really what you are looking for is other suggestions.  Under what compiler optimisation settings did you achieve 8ms? And indeed what compiler?  Both those things may make a significant difference.

Comment: When I see stuff like `rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress]` repeated a bunch of times that's a candidate for setting a variable and using the variable multiple times instead. Are you compiling a fully optimized build? As always, **inspect the assembly output of your code** to see what might be simplified or improved.

Comment: You could also use `uint_fast32_t`, `uint_fast8_t`, etc. if you don't need exactly that number of bits.

Comment: @tadman : true, but it is also the kind of invariant expression that an optimiser will spot and do the job for you.

Comment: @Clifford Some compilers I trust to do that. Others are paranoid and won't. Not sure what shape the STM32 compiler is in.

Comment: @tadman : STM32 is an ARM-Cortex and as such is supported by GCC, and ARMCC - version 6 of which is CLANG based, v5 was ARM proprietary - all are competent.

Comment: @Clifford Interesting and good to know. Thanks!

Comment: By canvassing "_ideas/thoughts_" you are likely to get fragments of answers, mostly as comments rather then answers, since it is unlikely that one answer for all the code will be optimal or that one person will have all the answers - because one could make any number of suggestions that may work or compete in combination.  As such the question lacks focus.

Comment: First thing I would try is unrolling the inner loop(s) to reduce branching.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are using `uint8_t` loop counters because you think they might be faster or save memory.  On an ARM Cortex-M, neither is likely  a plain `int` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for comments and tips. I'm using GCC and used the best optimization option for the function this is happening in. I agree the question lacks focus. I am/was more of looking for direction and tips on possible improvements. I will definitely try your suggestions and see what helps the performance.

Comment: @JustQiix: Please add definitions of arrays and constants?

Comment: @A.K. Edited the original post with declarations, constants and LUT's.

Comment: Your frame processing code takes 1.5 ms on my stmf723 at 216 MHz, which is about 15 cycles for the inner loop. The inner loop gets unrolled. I tried enabling and disabling caches but it makes little difference. I have some ideas but maybe trying to ask the compiler to optimize code better is an easier way. I use gcc with -O3.

Comment: 8 ms * 200M = 1.6M cycles, which divided by (8*8*8*40) gives 78 cycles. Seems too slow. Check what kind of assembly is produced.

Comment: The bit shifts look strange. I don't know the underlying format so I could be wrong, but shouldn't they be 8, 24 and 16 instead?

Comment: @JustQiix Ok so the 16 should be 15 then? It's not consistent.

Comment: @Lundin My last comment didnt explain it correctly, data looks like this 'XX11111111111111XX11111111111111'

Comment: @JustQiix Ah, so one possible performance improvement would be to memcpy that whole thing into a 4 byte array, then clear out the 2 undesired MSB in the bytes that have them. I'll post an example.

Comment: Actually, it is not clear still. Should the "X" bits be preserved or removed? If you right shift "XX111111" by 7, you preserve the left-most X but not the right-most X.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your program seems to run slower than expected from an STM32. You may need to look into what assembly is produced, compiler optimization settings, if MCU frequency is correct, if memory is too slow, etc. We don't have enough information to give a definite answer why. Your code seems to spend 8 ms * 200M / (8*8*8*40) = 78 cycles for each inner loop iteration. For reference, an stm32f723 only needs about 15 cycles, and an stm32f103 about 28 cycles (the code was adjusted to access smaller arrays in the latter case).
2. The LUT table is not needed as its content is very regular. Reading LUT values adds more memory reads, which may be a significant contribution. If I got your LUT generation code correctly, it produces the following numbers in the inner loop:

> ```
> Y1  Cb  Cr  Y2
> 0   128 192 1
> 2   129 193 3
> 4   130 194 5
> 6   131 195 7
> 64  132 196 65
> 66  133 197 67
> 68  134 198 69
> 70  135 199 71
> 8   136 200 9
> etc
> ```

The second and third columns are just consecutive numbers. The fourth column equals the first one plus one. And the first number needs a bit flip. You can try the following code (please check that it is correct):

```
uint32_t lutOffset = 0;
for(uint8_t i = 0; i < ROWS_PER_MCU; i++)
{
    for(uint8_t j = 0; j < WORDS_PER_MCU; j++)
    {
        uint32_t rawBufferAddress = (inputOffset+j) /* % 2048 */;
#if 0
        unsigned y_lut1 = jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Y_MCU_LUT[lutOffset];
        unsigned Cb_lut = jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Cb_MCU_422_LUT[lutOffset];
        unsigned Cr_lut = jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Cr_MCU_422_LUT[lutOffset];
        unsigned y_lut2 = jpegInputLUT.JPEG_Y_MCU_LUT[lutOffset+1];
#else
        unsigned y_lut1 = lutOffset | (j / 4) << 6 | (j % 4) << 1;
        unsigned Cb_lut = 128 + lutOffset + j;
        unsigned Cr_lut = 192 + lutOffset + j;
        unsigned y_lut2 = y_lut1 + 1;
#endif
        jpegInBuffer[y_lut1 + currentMCU] = (rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] & 0x7F);
        jpegInBuffer[Cb_lut + currentMCU] = ((rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] >> 7) & 0x7F);
        jpegInBuffer[Cr_lut + currentMCU] = ((rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] >> 23) & 0x7F);
        jpegInBuffer[y_lut2 + currentMCU] = ((rawBuffer[rawBufferAddress] >> 16) & 0x7F);
    }
    lutOffset += 8;
    inputOffset += 320;
}
```

This version takes about 20 cycles per iteration on my stm32f103, which is less than 6 ms even at its 72 MHz.

UPD. Another option is using one small lookup table instead of bit computations:

```
static const unsigned x[8] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 64, 66, 68, 70 };

//  unsigned y_lut1 = lutOffset | (j / 4) << 6 | (j % 4) << 1;
  unsigned y_lut1 = lutOffset + x[j];
```

This improves the inner loop timing to 18 (f103) / 7.5 (f723) cycles. For some reason, optimizing this expression for F723 does not work well. I would expect these options to give identical result since the inner loop is unrolled, but who knows.

3. As an additional optimization, probably not necessary, the output values can be combined into 32-bit words and written one word a time. This seems possible because LUT values come in blocks of four consecutive ones. For this, the inner loop can be converted to a nested loop of 2 by 4 iterations. Each 4 iterations of the innermost loop will produce one uint32_t for Cb, one uint32_t for Cr and two uint32_t for Y. *But is not worth doing.*

I measure run time with SysTick:

```
SysTick->LOAD = SysTick_LOAD_RELOAD_Msk;
SysTick->VAL = 0;
SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;

volatile unsigned t0 = SysTick->VAL;
f();
volatile unsigned t1 = t0 - SysTick->VAL;
```

I used output pins sometimes too, when connecting a debugger is not practical. Strictly speaking, both methods are not guaranteed to work because the compiler may move code across measurement points, but it has worked as intended for me (with gcc). Assembly inspection is needed to make sure that nothing fishy is going on.

Comment: Wow, thanks for you time and efforts. Your understanding of the conversion is correct. I've tried out your code and the excecution time has gone from ~8ms to about ~4.2ms also using gcc and -O3. I've measured this using a gpio pin and an oscilloscope. How did you measure your execution time if you don't mind me asking? Ill also take a look at how my assembly code is produced.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of micro optimisations that could be performed here that could provide an improvement.  Some may exhibit an improvement in debug build without compiler optimisation, only to have no advantage with optimisation.  It is possible even that some "clever" trick that is faster in debug if non-idiomatic could cause the optimiser to generate worse code that it might had you favoured clarity over performance.

All the obvious micro-optimisations such as loop unrolling the compiler optimiser will likely be able to perform for you without complicating the code or risking introducing errors.

One rather obvious improvement (regardless of whether or not it is faster), would be to change:

```
        for( uint8_t j = 0; j < WORDS_PER_MCU; j++ )
        {
            /* Mask 32 bit according to DCMI input format */
            uint32_t rawBufferAddress = inputOffset+j; // Calculate rawBuffer address here so it only has to be calculated once
            ...
```

to:

```
        uint32_t rawBufferAddress = inputOffset ;
        for( uint8_t j = 0; j < WORDS_PER_MCU; rawBufferAddress++, j++)
        {
            /* Mask 32 bit according to DCMI input format */
            ...
```

Your "*only has to be calculated once*" is actually `WORDS_PER_MCU` calculations, and an increment is likely to be faster than and addition and assignment.  At worst it will be no different.

I would similarly suggest moving all the other "end of loop increments such as `lutOffset+=2` into the respective `for` third expression also.  Not for performance, but for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to take a look at my post and your replies. I did not know you could change multiple variables in the third expression, will definitely implement this.

Comment: @JustQiix : You can use any valid expression in all three semi-colon delimited expressions in a `for`, and since C has the ["comma operator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) you can use a sequence of sub-expressions.

Comment: @JustQiix : Further if you avoid the unnecessary type constraints you have imposed on yourself, can do:  `for( int j = 0, rawBufferAddress = inputOffset; j < WORDS_PER_MCU; rawBufferAddress++, j++)` - not an optimisation, but reduces the scope of `rawBufferAddress` to just the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I can definitely see how this would give more clarity to the individual loops.